# PHP: dealing with quotes, escaping etc in string manipulation

Tags: php, string, escaping

I am making a certain class with complicated string manipulations.

Stuff works well with `'` and `"`. However one of the texts had some weird quotes at an angle like this: `”` and `“` and in my code, the appear as `â€` rather than actual quotes. That breakes my code, since its multiple characters, where it shouldn't have been.

Can somebody please explain why this is happening, and how do you work it around?

Comment: How did you got that text into your code? Did you pasted it from somewhere else? If that is the case, then your problem relates to text encoding.

Comment: That's a side effect of a bad character set conversion. e.g. stuffing UTF-8 text into an iso-8859 container.

Comment: @Nicolás yes, I copy pasted in my submit form.

Comment: @MarcB what is an `iso-8859 container`? is there a setting that I forgot to set to UTF-8?

Comment: it's something (a string, a database connection, a database field, etc...) where the character set is iso-8859 (or any other charset that ISN'T utf-8). when you do a direct copy into a different charset container, you tend to corrupt the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either use utf-8 encoding or replace all non-fitting characters.
these quotes has no spechial meaning though, you can ignore them.

as it was discovered in the comments, the problem was in using substr instead of mb_substr(). So, with the latter the problem solved.

Comment: then how do I use utf-8? my database is UTF-8 and the headers are UTF, however I never get to any of those, since I fail at the PHP manipulation before that.

Comment: there is some mistake in your utf setup. otherwise there will be no problem in displaying these quotes

Comment: would that be in my php.ini file? I am totally clueless right now

Comment: no, php ini has very little to do with encodings. are you sure your headers indeed utf?

Comment: I never get to headers. I have a string that causes problem before I get to the headers and load any page. Here is the problem `var_dump(strlen("”"));` gives me `int(3)`.

Comment: that's perfectly valid for the so-called "multybyte character". what is your problem?

Comment: The problem si that if I want to just cut this specific symbol out of the string, i get nonsense. So let met see if I understood it right - in the list of UTF-8 Characters, some are multibyte, and for that reason i always have to use mb_substr() instead of substr, is that right?

Comment: great! do you want to write the answer so i can mark it as right? Also, i had to set `default_charset` in `php.ini` to `utf-8` before all.

Comment: this directive is just to send an HTTP header. to set an encoding for the mb_* functions you have to use some mb_ function as well IO believe.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure this can be solved by adding `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` in the header.  This is caused because it can't read the “. Or you could just change it to normal "

Comment: this surrogate "header" will be ignored by the browser. Learn to use real HTTP headers.